# Sequence increase/decrease

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need help determining if the following sequences are increasing, decreasing or not monotnic. Any help would be great.

I think that for c) it is not monotonic as well as for a.

a) $\frac{\cos(n)}{5^n}$

b) $\frac{1}{5n+8}$

c) $\frac{n-5}{n+5}$

d) $\frac{\sqrt{n+5}}{8n+5}$

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

a) is not monotnic

b) is decreasing

c) $\frac{n-5}{n+5}=1-\frac{10}{n+5}$ is increasing

d) is decreasing.